# jquery - Sliding navigation on the right side of the browser

Tags: jquery, browser, navigation, sliding

anyone can help me on a sliding navigation? something like on the code, but executing the effect when the mouse position is on the right side of the browser.

```
$(document).hover(function () {
     $('#navSlider').show();
}, function () {
     $('#navSlider').hide();
});
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526457/jquery-mouse-position-relative-window

Answer (score 2):

create a div on top of the image container and position it to the right side of the image...  suppose u gave the  id for the div as `hoverright`.

then simply include the code as

```
$("#hoverright").live('hover',function(){
      $('#navSlider').show();
}, function () {
     $('#navSlider').hide();
});
```

Hope this will help..

Answer (score 1):

You could make a transparent floating div that is absolutely positioned on the right side of the page, taking up the full screen vertically and only as much as you need horizontally.  Then, apply the hover event to that div, and have your navSlider pop-up over it.