# Getting mouse x and y position according to screen js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I got this script that gets me the X and Y position of the mouse cursor so I can make a menu overlay where i clicked the mouse like this

```
$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
            $scope.currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
            $scope.currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
        });
```

My problem is that, when I scroll down the page, the position does follow.
So my question is. Is there a way to get the X and Y position of the mouse from the view that is shown in the browser? So that it's only takes the cords from the "grid" you are currently seeing?

Comment: Get the `window.scrollTop` value, and subtract etc.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526457/jquery-mouse-position-relative-window for reference, see which solution works best for you

Comment: thank you. im gonna do that. guess this is a duplicate question then